# Elasticsearch performance degrades after upgrading from 6.7 to 7.10

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

We are trying to migrate the elasticsearch from 6.7 to 7.10 by using `amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch` which are 0.9.0 and 1.13.2 and we plan to move to 8 without using that image.

The indices are reindexed in the new elasticsearch cluster.

And we did some comparisons.

#### simple load test is slow

A simple load test indicates that the same set of queries uses 91ms per request in 6 while it takes 112ms in 7.

An example query looks like this: https://gist.github.com/teanoon/be17fc76a99460c6ec669222c76dbe60

#### profile shows slower parts

The profile detail shows a lot of queries take 100% longer in 7 than it in 6.

```
{
  "type": "PointInSetQuery",
  "description": "brandIds:{59 (...omitted 100 brands) 31389}",
  "time_6_baseline": "1.2531 ms",
  "time_7_baseline": "4.4807 ms"
}
```

Breakdowns with a same query have huge differences.

[es6 and es7 breakdown comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny8sl.png)

The left one comes from ES6 and the right one is ES7.

#### page cache is used

We know that the elasticsearch 7 has a off-heap changes and [it moves terms index out of the heap](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/breaking-changes-7.0.html#_off_heap_terms_index).
so we checked the page cache:
`sudo lsof +D /mnt/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices/wu47nPk0TEuVBzLo3WEOsQ`
and it looks like this:

```
COMMAND   PID          USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
java    30779 elasticsearch  mem    REG  259,0 108409303 15728663 /mnt/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices/Dznr2xCpSS6VDJV0qLDkqQ/7/index/_5.cfs
java.........................................................................cfs
java.........................................................................doc
java.........................................................................dvd
java.........................................................................kdd
java.........................................................................kdi
java.........................................................................nvd
java.........................................................................tim
java.........................................................................tip(these files are loaded in mem)
java    30779 elasticsearch  mem    REG  259,0     71445 15729187 /mnt/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices/Dznr2xCpSS6VDJV0qLDkqQ/4/index/_9_Lucene84_0.tip
java    30779 elasticsearch  373r   REG  259,0  33969522 15728698 /mnt/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices/Dznr2xCpSS6VDJV0qLDkqQ/1/index/_d_Lucene84_0.pos
java.........................................................................ckp
java.........................................................................fdt
java.........................................................................fdx
java.........................................................................lock
java.........................................................................pos
java.........................................................................tlog(these files are not loaded in mem)
java    30779 elasticsearch  731w   REG  259,0        88 15728658 /mnt/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices/Dznr2xCpSS6VDJV0qLDkqQ/7/translog/translog.ckp
```

we tried with different index store settings([change the store type to mmapfs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/index-modules-store.html), [preload custom files](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/preload-data-to-file-system-cache.html)) and they load more files into the mem like elasticsearch 6 but the overall performance is still not as good as 6.

#### query optimization

Query optimization should improve the performance but it doesn't cover the gaps between 6 and 7.

We tried using `filter` to replace `must` and have some improvement but it doesn't fill the gap between 6 and 7.

#### index and cluster brief

The testing index and cluster are:

- 1 index with 2.6 million products and 9 shards 1 replica. 5.8gb(11.6 gb including replica)
- we tried different Elasticsearch heap size: 8G and 15G
- The cluster has 2 nodes. Each node is a i3.xlarge(4cpu 30.5GB SSD)

#### question

So the question is what causes the performance issue?

Comment: My first observation doesn't seek to solve the problem, but I'm just curious why you have **9 primary shards** for such a small index (5GB is tiny) with **only two data nodes**?

Comment: @Val This is our production settings. I tried 1 shard solution but it only gets slower.